# The matrix is cut off

Tags: pdf, matrices

I wrote a long matrix in LaTeX

```
\begin{equation}
\rho H =
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\rho_{11} \hbar \omega_{1} +\rho_{13} \hbar \Omega_{p} cos(t\omega_{p})  & 
\rho_{12} \hbar \omega_{2}+ \rho_{13} \hbar \Omega_{c} cos(t\omega_{c}) & 
\rho_{11} \hbar \Omega_{p} cos(t\omega_{p})+  \rho_{12} \hbar \Omega_{c} cos(t\omega_{c}) + \rho_{13} \hbar \omega_{3}\\

\rho_{21} \hbar \omega_{1} +\rho_{23} \hbar \Omega_{p} cos(t\omega_{p})  & 
\rho_{22} \hbar \omega_{2}+ \rho_{23} \hbar \Omega_{c} cos(t\omega_{c}) &   
\rho_{21} \hbar \Omega_{p} cos(t\omega_{p})+  \rho_{22} \hbar \Omega_{c} cos(t\omega_{c}) + \rho_{23} \hbar \omega_{3} \\

\hbar \Omega_{p} cos(t\Omega_{p}) & \hbar \Omega_{c} cos(t\Omega_{c}) & \hbar  \omega_{3}
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
```

The problem is when I transformed the text to PDF 
the matrix I get is cutting in the PDF (not viewed all in the pdf page)
[image]
Does anyone know how I fix that?

Comment: First of all, use `\cos` and `\sin`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the matrix within the page margins with the default layout (10 pt) and the `geometry` package, which widens the default text block, if you use the `medsize` environment (from the `nccmath` package). This environment makes formulae ~80 % of `\displaystyle` and if you reduce the value of `\arraycolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{3 pt}
\begin{medsize}ρ H = \begin{pmatrix}
ρ_{11} \hbar ω_{1} +ρ_{13} \hbar Ω_{p} \cos(tω_{p}) &
ρ_{12} \hbar ω_{2}+ ρ_{13} \hbar Ω_{c} \cos(tω_{c}) &
ρ_{11} \hbar Ω_{p} \cos(tω_{p})+ ρ_{12} \hbar Ω_{c} \cos(tω_{c}) + ρ_{13} \hbar ω_{3}\\
ρ_{21} \hbar ω_{1} +ρ_{23} \hbar Ω_{p} \cos(tω_{p}) &
ρ_{22} \hbar ω_{2}+ ρ_{23} \hbar Ω_{c} \cos(tω_{c}) &
ρ_{21} \hbar Ω_{p} \cos(tω_{p})+ ρ_{22} \hbar Ω_{c} \cos(tω_{c}) + ρ_{23} \hbar ω_{3} \\
\hbar Ω_{p} \cos(tΩ_{p}) & \hbar Ω_{c} \cos(tΩ_{c}) & \hbar ω_{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{medsize}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to state that loading the `geometry` package implicitly widens the text block. Without this device, the `pmatrix` won't fit even with `medsize` being in force.

Comment: @Mico: I had forgotten this point (I still don't know why simply loading geometry does so). I'll add it at once.

Comment: thanks , its look like I don't have the package {mathtools} where can I find it ? and how I add it to the Latex?

Comment: @saja: I bet you're under MiKTeX. Am I right?

Answer (score 7):

Problems such as this are almost always best fixed by improved notation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\rho H =
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{11} \hbar \omega_{1} +\rho_{13} \hbar k_p  & \rho_{12} \hbar \omega_{2} + \rho_{13} \hbar k_c &
\rho_{11} \hbar k_p +  \rho_{12} \hbar k_c + \rho_{13} \hbar \omega_{3}\\
\rho_{21} \hbar \omega_{1} +\rho_{23} \hbar k_p  & \rho_{22} \hbar \omega_{2}+ \rho_{23} \hbar k_c &
\rho_{21} \hbar k_p +  \rho_{22} \hbar \Omega_{c} k_c + \rho_{23} \hbar \omega_{3} \\
\hbar k_p & \hbar k_c & \hbar \omega_{3}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $k_c= \Omega_c \cos(t\omega_c)$ and $k_p= \Omega_p \cos(t\omega_p)$.
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix]

Note the use of `pmatrix` from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) which provides better spacing than array by default.

Answer (score 5):

Given the complexity of the elements in the matrix, your readers may appreciate if you list the elements one by one, in a list-like manner:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\rho H &=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\shortintertext{where}
a_{11} &= \rho_{11} \hbar \omega_{1} +\rho_{13} \hbar \Omega_{p} \cos(t\omega_{p})   \notag \\
a_{12} &= \rho_{12} \hbar \omega_{2}+ \rho_{13} \hbar \Omega_{c} \cos(t\omega_{c})  \notag \\
a_{13} &= \rho_{11} \hbar \Omega_{p} \cos(t\omega_{p})+  \rho_{12} \hbar \Omega_{c} \cos(t\omega_{c}) + \rho_{13} \hbar \omega_{3} \notag \\
a_{21} &= \rho_{21} \hbar \omega_{1} +\rho_{23} \hbar \Omega_{p} \cos(t\omega_{p})   \notag \\
a_{22} &= \rho_{22} \hbar \omega_{2}+ \rho_{23} \hbar \Omega_{c} \cos(t\omega_{c})  \notag \\
a_{23} &= \rho_{21} \hbar \Omega_{p} \cos(t\omega_{p})+  \rho_{22} \hbar \Omega_{c} \cos(t\omega_{c}) + \rho_{23} \hbar \omega_{3}  \notag \\
a_{31} &= \hbar \Omega_{p} \cos(t\Omega_{p})  \notag \\
a_{32} &= \hbar \Omega_{c} \cos(t\Omega_{c})  \notag \\
a_{33} &= \hbar \omega_{3} \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps even with extra line breaks between the "rows" of coefficients: $a_{11}&=\\a_{12}&=\\a_{13}\\ \\ a_{21}&=\\$ etc.